# Elastic Search Filter by comparing same field from different documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

In my index, I have documents like this:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "createdAt": 1.6117508295E12
}

{
    "name": "name1",
    "createdAt": 1.6117508296E12
}

{
    "name": "name",
    "createdAt": 1.6117508297E12
}
```

I want to write a query in such a way so that I can compare between between the name field between any 2 documents and get unique results. The result should be like this:

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "createdAt": 1.6117508296E12
}

{
    "name": "name",
    "createdAt": 1.6117508297E12
}
```

I am also using from and size in my elastic query.
I have tried using collapse but that gives me less number of results as  per the size.

I am using elastic 7.15.2

Comment: can you explain the logic of your expected result?

Comment: actually i want to get unique documents (on the basis of name field). In case of a match the first one should be picked.

Comment: "name": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "fields": { "lowerCase": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer"
                        }}}

Comment: these are the current mappings for name keyword

Comment: You need to use the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) with top_hits(with size=1, sorted by createdAt). Below is the working query on sample data your provided.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "unique": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "name.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "unique_names": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "createdAt": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
"aggregations": {
        "unique": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "name",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "unique_names": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "71625371",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "name": "name",
                                        "createdAt": 1.6117508295E12
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1.61175083E12
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "name1",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "unique_names": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "71625371",
                                    "_id": "2",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "name": "name1",
                                        "createdAt": 1.6117508296E12
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1.61175083E12
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. I will try this solution and update. To add to it, is there any way to compare the data of name field in case insensitive manner?

Comment: @SakshamSingh, that would not be recommended as you need the terms aggregation and aggregation on text field is costly so we need to use it on `.keyword` form of your `name` field. if you really want we need to change the index mapping and use the keyword normalizer which converts everything to lowercase and than we can do it.